# По соображениям безопасности использование фреймов запрещено; чтобы их удалить, нажмите OK

Tags: дефект

Сообщение про фреймы иногда появляется при массовом открытии страниц ruSO при запуске браузера (Хрома), хотя на самом деле никаких фреймов нет.

Message about frames sometimes appears when launching a browser (Chrome) with a lot of ruSO pages opened. And there are no any frames.

> По соображениям безопасности использование фреймов запрещено; чтобы их удалить, нажмите OK.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Расширения браузера какие-то используются? Есть [древнючая тема](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84462/339911) на MSE о подобной ситуации.

Comment: @alexolut, ничего особенного. И если бы проблема была в расширениях, оно б свегда так было, а это рандомно и всего пара страниц из сотни.

Comment: ничего особенного != нет расширений.

Comment: @alexolut, https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtAul.png - вот.

Comment: У меня тоже было такое. Довольно редко выскакивало, в основном, когда слишком часто нажимаешь кнопки "Назад" и "Вперед"

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, кстати да, на эти кнопки тоже было.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight а от частого рефреша может быть и [такое](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41665729#41665729).

Comment: @alexolut, back/forward не перезагружают страницу)